# Samba login failure: getpwuid failed

Tags: linux, authentication, samba

I cannot access a remote drive using Windows or smbclient; my authentication appears successful according to the samba log file, but `getpwuid` fails. The server (remote) is running CentOS 7.2 and Samba 4.2.3. The client is CentOS 7.2 and smbclient 4.2.3.  The logfile shows:

```
[2017/05/06 22:57:48.729284,  2] ../source3/auth/auth.c:305(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [developer_prod] -> [developer_prod] -> [developer_prod] succeeded
[2017/05/06 22:57:48.731091,  1] ../source3/auth/token_util.c:430(add_local_groups)
  SID S-1-5-21-4007675785-2624567327-467545301-1000 -> getpwuid(16777216) failed
[2017/05/06 22:57:48.731164,  1] ../source3/smbd/sesssetup.c:280(reply_sesssetup_and_X_spnego)
  Failed to generate session_info (user and group token) for session setup: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

Strangely, the SID corresponds to a local user:

```
# wbinfo -s S-1-5-21-4007675785-2624567327-467545301-1000         
NY4010\developer_prod 1
```

(ny4010 is my samba server machine) Even though on the client I am logging in using a domain user:

```
$ smbclient -U 'my_domain\developer_prod' \\\\ny4010\\release 'password'
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

Here is my smb.conf file:

```
[global]
   workgroup = MYDOMAIN
   password server = my_domain_server.mydomain.local
   realm = MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
   security = ads
   idmap config * : range = 16777216-33554431
   template homedir = /home/%U
   template shell = /bin/bash
   kerberos method = secrets only
   winbind use default domain = true
   winbind offline logon = false
   log level = 2
   encrypt passwords = yes
       unix extensions = no
        server string = Samba Server Version %v
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        security = ads
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        realm = MYDOMAIN.LOCAL
        password server = my_domain_server.mydomain.local
        local master = no
[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        browseable = no
        writable = yes
[release]
       comment = Shared directory: /prod
       path = /prod
       browseable = yes
       read only = no
       valid users = developer_prod
       guest ok = yes
       public = yes
       follow symlinks = yes
       wide links = yes
       force user = developer_prod
[log]
       comment = Shared directory: /prod/log
       path = /prod/log
       browseable = yes
       read only = yes
       guest ok = yes
       public = yes
```

my nsswitch.conf file looks like:
    passwd:     files winbind

I think the smoking gun here is that a local user's SID is showing up in that getpwuid failed line...

Comment: Did you solved your issue ? I got exactly the same problem.... :(

Comment: No. I switched to sssd, using RedHat's instructions here https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rhel-ad-integration-deployment-guidelines-v1.5.pdf, starting at page 56. Strangely, it was only the "developer_prod" user that was having the problem. Other users could authenticate properly.

Answer (score 3):

For us everything was working till Samba version 4.8.3 on Centos 7, it broke with samba update samba-4.9.1-6.el7.x86_64.

I was getting this error :

> [2019/10/04 11:28:52.458451,  2] ../source3/auth/auth.c:316(auth_check_ntlm_password)
>     check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [singh] -> [singh] -> [singh] succeeded
>
> [2019/10/04 11:28:52.458736,  1] ../source3/auth/token_util.c:561(add_local_groups)
>     SID S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-16811 -> getpwuid(50000) failed

So after hours of troubleshooting adding **winbind** instead of **sss** to "/etc/nsswitch.conf" worked.

```
passwd:     files winbind
shadow:     files
group:      files winbind
```

Also added these new options to smb.conf

```
idmap config *:backend = tdb
idmap config *:range = 1000-9999
## map ids from the domain  the ranges may not overlap !
idmap config LIBRARY : backend = rid
idmap config LIBRARY : range = 10000-999999
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clear Winbind cache

How to clear Winbind cache

Stop the Winbind service :

```
[root@danny root]#  service winbind stop
```

Stop the samba service if you have it :

```
[root@danny root]#  service smb stop
```

Clear the Samba Net cache:

```
[root@danny root]#  net cache flush
```

Delete the Winbind cache :

```
[root@danny samba]# cd /var/lib/samba/
# mkdir old && mv *.tdb old/.
```

Start the samba service if you have it :

```
[root@danny samba]# service smb start
```

Start the Winbind service

```
[root@danny samba]# service winbind start
```

Now you can check.